# Receiver has no segue with identifier error

Tags: ios

I am getting an error

```
2014-04-09 01:42:23.599 appname[9584:60b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Receiver (<LoginViewController: 0x9a9cda0>) has no segue with identifier 'login''
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x0263c1e4 __exceptionPreprocess + 180
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x023bb8e5 objc_exception_throw + 44
    2   UIKit                               0x0119c48c -[UIViewController shouldPerformSegueWithIdentifier:sender:] + 0
    3   appname                   0x00002fea -[LoginViewController viewDidAppear:] + 170
    4   UIKit                               0x0119e099 -[UIViewController _setViewAppearState:isAnimating:] + 526
    5   UIKit                               0x0119e617 -[UIViewController __viewDidAppear:] + 146
    6   UIKit                               0x011a0014 __64-[UIViewController viewDidMoveToWindow:shouldAppearOrDisappear:]_block_invoke + 44
    7   UIKit                               0x0119e9aa -[UIViewController _executeAfterAppearanceBlock] + 63
    8   UIKit                               0x010990d0 ___afterCACommitHandler_block_invoke_2 + 33
    9   UIKit                               0x01099055 _applyBlockToCFArrayCopiedToStack + 403
    10  UIKit                               0x01098e9a _afterCACommitHandler + 568
    11  CoreFoundation                      0x0260436e __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 30
    12  CoreFoundation                      0x026042bf __CFRunLoopDoObservers + 399
    13  CoreFoundation                      0x025e2254 __CFRunLoopRun + 1076
    14  CoreFoundation                      0x025e19d3 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 467
    15  CoreFoundation                      0x025e17eb CFRunLoopRunInMode + 123
    16  GraphicsServices                    0x042205ee GSEventRunModal + 192
    17  GraphicsServices                    0x0422042b GSEventRun + 104
    18  UIKit                               0x0107bf9b UIApplicationMain + 1225
    19  appname                             0x00004e3d main + 141
    20  libdyld.dylib                       0x02ed9701 start + 1
    21  ???                                 0x00000001 0x0 + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
(lldb)
```

However I do not think I am doing something wrong with my code  this is my viewdiappear. What did I miss out so that this kind of error is created?

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    PFUser *user = [PFUser currentUser];
    if (user.username != nil) {
        [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"login" sender:self];
    }
}
```

Comment: Any update on your question?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you haven't set the name of the segue in the storyboard. The picture below is the name of one of my segues, for you, the text box would contain simply login.

[image]

It can also happen when you forget to "Embed" the storyboard in Navigation controller:

[image]

Comment: This isn't helping me. I have set an identifier for the segue

Comment: Check your segues if they're linked up well and start/end where you want them to start/end. The error console doesn't lie. If you're 100% sure it does, try cleaning the code and building it again.

Answer (score 0):

What the error is telling you is that although your storyboard may *contain* a segue called `@"login"`, it does not *emanate* from this LoginViewController (the one that is currently `self`).

You may think it does, but trust me, the runtime knows more than you do.

Comment: I have the self so that if the user is already logged in it will automatically perform a segue

Comment: Right, that all seems correct, however the object SELF, the ViewController you are calling performSegue on is either not connected in the storyboard(double-check), or the segue is missing its identifier in the storyboard(double-check).